Does StoreKit.Framework need to be signed for in-app purchases (Unity Game)?
I'm uploading a game to the apple app store and Unity is returning IAP Initialization failed: NoProductsAvailable, however the products are 100% configured properly in the store and all I did in XCode is disable "Embed Swift Standard Libraries." I know StoreKit can be used for testing but do I need to embed & sign it for Unity to connect to app store connect and get the IAP products? If so, how do I distribute it to app store connect without failing?

